# Put text html into database

Tags: php, mysql

I want import a data (from a `form`) in my database but i've this error :

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in /homepages/38/htdocs/index2.php on line 7
```

and the script is

```
   <?php
//Connecting to sql db.
$connect = mysqli_connect("","","","");

//Sending form data to sql db.
mysqli_query($connect,"INSERT INTO posts (email, pseudo)
VALUES ('$_POST[email]', '$_POST[pseudo]')";
?>
```

What is the error ?
Thank you

Comment: You need to add a `)`

Comment: One problem in you code is `$_POST[pseudo]`. You should write array parameter as string. Also you should close sting when you want to use variable or write variable in `{}`.

Comment: @PotatoesPower. I have provided with the explanation and solution over to the error that you face now. Share thought about your view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$email=$_POST['email'];

$pseudo=$_POST['pseudo']; 



mysqli_query($connect,"INSERT INTO `posts` (`email`, `pseudo`) VALUES ('$email', '$pseudo');");
```

Comment: The first problem solver but new problem added. `'$_POST['email']'` is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

### Solution

- You have not concatenated the `$_POST[]` variable correctly.
- You have been missing the close brace for the mysqli_query opening.
- It is advised to have a separate query and then to execute the `mysqli_query()`.

#### Necessary Checks:

- Ensure that you have given the name for the input type in the form attributes.
- Have a check that whether you have called the name what you have given in the form at the PHP code while insert.

(E.g) - Input Attribute needs to be like this

```
<input type="email" name="email" value="" />
```

Like this you have to provide for all the Input  types.

**PHP Code**

Usage of the `mysqli::real_escape_string` is better if you use it avoids SQL Injection.

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
// escape variables for security
$email=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['email']);
$pseudo=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['pseudo']); 
$stmt = "INSERT INTO posts (`email`, `pseudo`)VALUES('".$email."','".$pseudo."')";
$query = mysqli_query($con,$stmt);
if($query)
{
echo "Inserted Successfully";
}
else
{
// Handle Error over here.
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have missed quote inside POST .Check below code

```
<?php
//Connecting to sql db.
$connect = mysqli_connect("","","","");

$sql ="INSERT INTO posts (email, pseudo)VALUES('".$_POST['email']."','".$_POST['pseudo']."')";
//Sending form data to sql db.
mysqli_query($connect,$sql);
?>
```